# Understand one edge case of block memory management in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

the code below will crash because of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
typedef void(^myBlock)(void);

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *tmp = [self getBlockArray];
    myBlock block = tmp[0];
    block();
}

- (id)getBlockArray {
    int val = 10;
//crash version
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            ^{NSLog(@"blk0:%d", val);},
            ^{NSLog(@"blk1:%d", val);}, nil];
//won't crash version
//    return @[^{NSLog(@"block0: %d", val);}, ^{NSLog(@"block1: %d", val);}];
}
```

the code runs in iOS 9 with ARC enabled. And I was trying to figure out the reason that lead to crash.

by `po tmp` in lldb I found

```
(lldb) po tmp
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa0f1546330>(
<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7fa0f15a0fd0>,
<__NSStackBlock__: 0x7fff524e2b60>
)
```

whereas in the won't crash version

```
(lldb) po tmp
<__NSArrayI 0x7f9db481e6a0>(
<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7f9db27e09a0>,
<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7f9db2718f50>
)
```

So the most possible reason I could come up with is when ARC release the **NSStackBlock** the crash happen. But why would so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand that if you want to store a block past the scope where it's declared, you need to copy it and store the copy instead.

The reason for this because of an optimization where blocks which capture variables are initially located on the stack, rather than dynamically allocated like a regular object. (Let's ignore blocks which don't capture variables for the moment, since they can be implemented as a global instance.) So when you write a block literal, like `foo = ^{ ...};`, that's effectively like assigning to `foo` a pointer to a hidden local variable declared in that same scope, something like `some_block_object_t hiddenVariable; foo = &hiddenVariable;` This optimization reduces the number of object allocations in the many cases where a block is used synchronously and never outlives the scope where it was created.

Like a pointer to a local variable, if you bring the pointer outside the scope of the thing it pointed to, you have a dangling pointer, and dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior. Performing a copy on a block moves a stack to the heap if necessary, where it is memory-managed like all other Objective-C objects, and returns a pointer to the heap copy (and if the block is already a heap block or global block, it simply returns the same pointer).

Whether the particular compiler uses this optimization or not in a particular circumstance is an implementation detail, but you cannot assume anything about how it's implemented, so you must always copy if you store a block pointer in a place that will outlive the current scope (e.g. in a instance or global variable, or in a data structure that may outlive the scope). Even if you knew how it was implemented, and know that in a particular case copying is not necessary (e.g. it is a block that doesn't capture variables, or copying must already have been done), you should not rely on that, and you should still always copy when you store it in a place that will outlive the current scope, as good practice.

Passing a block as an argument to a function or method is somewhat complicated. If you pass a block pointer as an argument to a function parameter whose declared compile-time type is a block-pointer type, then that function would in turn be responsible for copying it if it were to outlive its scope. So in this case, you wouldn't need to worry about copying it, without needing to know what the function did.

If, on the other hand, you pass a block pointer as an argument to a function parameter whose declared compile-time type is a non-block object pointer type, then that function wouldn't be taking responsibility for any block copying, because for all it knows it's just a regular object, that just needs to be retained if stored in a place that outlives the current scope. In this case, if you think that the function may possibly store the value beyond the end of the call, you should copy the block before passing it, and pass the copy instead.

By the way, this is also true for any other case where a block-pointer type is assigned or converted to a regular object-pointer type; the block should be copied and the copy assigned, because anyone who gets the regular object-pointer value wouldn't be expected to do any block copying considerations.

---

ARC complicates the situation somewhat. The ARC specification [specifies](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks) some situations where blocks are implicitly copied. For example, when storing to a variable of compile-time block-pointer type (or any other place where ARC requires a retain on a value of compile-time block-pointer type), ARC requires that the incoming value be copied instead of retained, so the programmer doesn't have to worry about explicitly copying blocks in those cases.

> With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a
>   `__strong` parameter variable or reading a `__weak` variable, whenever
>   these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it
>   has the effect of a `Block_copy`.

However, as an exception, the ARC specification does not guarantee that blocks only passed as arguments are copied.

> The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is
>   used only as an argument to a call.

So whether to explicitly copy blocks passed as arguments to a function is still something the programmer has to consider.

Now, the ARC implementation in recent versions of Apple's Clang compiler has an undocumented feature where it will add implicit block copies to some of the places where blocks are passed as arguments, even though the ARC specification doesn't require it. ("undocumented" because I cannot find any Clang documentation to this effect.) In particular, it appears that it defensively always adds implicit copies when passing an expression of block-pointer type to a parameter of non-block object pointer type. In fact, as demonstrated by CRD, it also adds an implicit copy when converting from a block-pointer type to a regular object-pointer type, so this is the more general behavior (since it includes the argument passing case).

However, it appears that the current version of the Clang compiler does not add implicit copies when passing a value of block-pointer type as varargs. C varargs are not type-safe, and it is impossible for the caller to know what types the function expects. Arguably, if Apple wants to error on the side of safety, since there's no way of knowing what the function expects, they should add implicit copies always in this case too. However, since this whole thing is an undocumented feature anyway, I wouldn't say it's a bug. In my opinion, then programmer should never rely on blocks that are only passed as arguments being implicitly copied in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I believe C varargs are not type-safe  is a more precise explanation for this situation.

Comment: @dopcn - newacct and I tend to disagree on what the specification states in regard to blocks and ARC. Unfortunately Apple's documentation isn't always as clear and comprehensive, and to be fair not just Apple's, so there is a certain amount of interpretation involved. Please do submit your case as a bug to Apple; they may fix it, say it works as intended, or just say nothing; but you will have alerted them. If they do come back with a useful response you can add it to your question above as an addendum to help others.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**:

You have found a compiler bug, possibly a re-introduced one, and you should report it at http://bugreport.apple.com.

**Longer Answer**:

This wasn't always a bug, it used to be a *feature* ;-) When Apple first introduced blocks they also introduced an *optimisation* in how they implemented them; however unlike normal compiler optimisations which are essentially transparent to the code they required programmers to sprinkle calls to a special function, `block_copy()`, in various places to make the optimisation work.

Over the years Apple removed the need for this, but only for programmers using ARC (though they could have done so for MRC users as well), and today the optimisation should be just that and programmers should no longer need to help the compiler along.

But you've just found a case where the compiler gets it wrong.

Technically you have a case a *type loss*, in this case where something known to be a block is passed as `id` - reducing the known type information, and in particular type loss involving the second or subsequent argument in a variable argument list. When you look at your array with `po tmp` you see the first value is correct, the compiler gets that one right despite there being type loss, but it fails on the next argument.

The literal syntax for an array does not rely on variadic functions and the code produced is correct. However `initWithObjects:` does, and it goes wrong.

*Workaround*:

If you add a cast to `id` to the second (and any subsequent) blocks then the compiler produces the correct code:

```
return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        ^{NSLog(@"blk0:%d", val);},
        (id)^{NSLog(@"blk1:%d", val);},
        nil];
```

This appears to be sufficient to wake the compiler up.

HTH

Comment: workaround verified. Thanks for your answer. But I want to know more about the crash reason. Without type cast the `NSStackBlock ` is also alive and runs when called. Why release it will lead to crash? Or Is't something else that lead to the crash?

Comment: An `NSStackBlock` is not a normal object - its a result of the optimisation mentioned above - and it should never be stored in an array (or any other object). It exists solely to be passed as an argument to a method, and only works as long as the caller - the method that created it to pass to another - is still active on the call stack. Violate any of these rules and all bets are off, and the compiler unhelpfully violated them for you.